# Django complex Query through database API

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, many-to-many

I am using django 1.7, python 3.4
I have a model class called 'EnterpriseProfile' which is in one to one relationship with a class named 'Enterprise'. Also there is another model 'User' which has a many to many relationship with 'Enterprise'. Now, in 'EnterpriseProfile' model I want to create a function that returns all the user related to that enterprise.
What would be the best way to achieve this through django database API or otherwise using raw SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code would help, but I believe that doing this inside EnterpriseProfile

note: this depends on how you named some fields.

you don't need a function:

```
profile = EnterpriseProfile.objects.get(pk=1)  # or whatever to get the object
# next returns all users related to that enterprise in the M2M
profile.enterprise.users.all()
```

Comment: Actually the 'Enterprise class does not contain a field named 'user'. the model named user has a many to many relation with the enterprise.

Comment: then django will make a `user` relationship inside Enterprise. read the M2M docs.